# want long-polling using restful API of jersey 2

Tags: java, rest, long-polling, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

***My requirement:***

I want to make API like `dropbox's` [`/longpoll_delta`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#longpoll-delta),I have useed `jerser 2` in java for my `restful`. Actually I want to notify all client when there is change found on server. So server may take 2hr or more then notify all its client that i have some update. I don't want to use `comet`, `websocket` etc for security purpose.

1> Suggest how can i made such API ?

***My effor :***
I have created [Asynchronous Server API](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#async)

`Server code:`

```
@GET
    @Path("/longpoll")
    @ManagedAsync
    public void async(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse)
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                String result = veryExpensiveOperation();
                asyncResponse.resume(result);
            }

            private String veryExpensiveOperation()
            {
                try
                {
                    // put some long running code here
                    Thread.sleep(60000);
                    return "Hello World";
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return "error";
                }

            }
        }).start();
    }
```

So now for testing this i have created client

`Client code:`

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Invocation;
import javax.ws.rs.client.InvocationCallback;
import javax.ws.rs.client.WebTarget;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;

public class JersyClient
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
    {
        ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient(clientConfig);
        WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080");
        Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder = target.path("MyApp_3_3_5/api/1/longpoll").request();
        invocationBuilder.header("Authorization", "Bearer yBOrnV6zlOrgoYxrMsfQ_BYZ5p37gALB");
        final Future<Response> future = invocationBuilder.async().get(new InvocationCallback<Response>()
        {
            @Override
            public void completed(Response response)
            {
                System.out.println("Response status code "
                        + response.getStatus() + " received.");
                System.out.println("In response " + response.readEntity(String.class));
            }

            @Override
            public void failed(Throwable throwable)
            {
                System.out.println("Invocation failed.");
                throwable.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        Response response = future.get();
        System.out.println("your response " + response.readEntity(String.class));
        // get() waits for the response to be ready
        System.out.println("Go ahead");
    }
}
```

But this not working properly.
`OutPut:`

```
Response status code 200 received.
In response 
your response 
Go ahead
```

So here client is not wait for actual response that server send after 1 minute.

1. Is server code have any problem ?
2. Why client not wait for actual response ?
3. Should i achieve long_pooling using this way ?
4. if server send response after 2hr then in such case is this working ?